# Mysql fill date gaps

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I'm trying to get values from dataTable for the last 7 days, if there is no data for specific date zero should be filled in the output:

```
SELECT calendar.dt, COALESCE(SUM(weight*price),0) AS amount
FROM
    (SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS dt
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY) calendar
LEFT JOIN dataTable ON calendar.dt = DATE(dataTable.sold_at);
```

Request above returns only one record:

[image]

Please advise what is wrong with SQL request?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `group by` Is missing.

```
SELECT calendar.dt, COALESCE(SUM(weight*price),0) AS amount
FROM
    (SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS dt
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 2 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 3 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 5 DAY
       UNION ALL SELECT CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 DAY) calendar
LEFT JOIN dataTable ON calendar.dt = DATE(dataTable.sold_at)
Group by calendar.dt
;
```

SQL fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f151a8e/4